# Stencil buffer and transparent pixels

Tags: directx, directx11

Do transparent pixels cause a stencil buffer operation (increment, decrement, etc.) to be executed?

My understanding was that only opaque pixels cause a stencil buffer operation, transparent pixels have no effect on the buffer. However in my application transparent pixels do seem to cause the stencil buffer to be written.

Do I have to set up a special blendstate in order to achieve transparent pixels to have no effect?

Answer (score 1):

DirectX9 was the last revision to support alpha-testing.

For DirectX10+:
In fact, transparent pixels do have an influence on the stencil buffer. In order to avoid altering the depth/stencil, you omit the pixel:

```
if (pixel.a < 0.1) discard;

clip(pixel.a < 0.1f ? -1 : 1); //omit if parameter evaluates to less than 0

clip(pixel.a - 0.1f);
```

This uses 0.1f to determine "close enough" similar to float.Epsilon.

**Be aware:** This disables early-z testing and may cause significant and/or unacceptable performance loss.

Comment: Sounds right.  "Transparent" pixels by default update all ouput buffers, unless manually discard them or you have alpha testing on.

Comment: As a minor note, testing if a == 0 might be a bad idea because of texture sampling interpolation. You should do if (a < 0.01) or so, or even define a higher cutoff value like 0.5.

Comment: thanks for both of your comments. @Sean: If i understood correctly, alpha testing has been removed in DirectX 11, so using the shader is the only way?

Comment: guess so.  shaders are the future.

Comment: @Sean: right, it is just that an `if` in a shader always makes me a bit nervous. But according to this, probably there is no reason to be: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5340237/how-much-performance-do-conditionals-and-unused-samplers-textures-add-to-sm2-3-p